# Insert Rows and fill/replicate values

Tags: vba, excel

So...I've searched a good amount on how to do this and while I can get a portion of it to work, I can't seem to figure out how to get all the pieces working

My initial data looks like the following and tells me how many rows each Value in the Title Column needs (e.g. Value1 will have 3 rows, Value2 will have one row, etc)

```
Title   Audit Period    Target Count
Value1    2013-Q1                  3
Value2    2013-Q1                  1
Value3    2013-Q2                  3
Value4    2013-Q3                  4
Value5    2013-Q4                  2
```

I would like to have, through VBA, a way to click a button and it format/populate the above information as follows:

```
Title   Audit Period
Value1  2013-Q1
Value1  2013-Q1
Value1  2013-Q1
Value2  2013-Q1
Value3  2013-Q2
Value3  2013-Q2
Value3  2013-Q2
Value4  2013-Q3
Value4  2013-Q3
Value4  2013-Q3
Value4  2013-Q3
Value5  2013-Q4
Value5  2013-Q4
```

I don't care where the transformed data is placed...the code can overwrite the starting data or place the results in a separate tab...or whatever.

Thank you for any assistance you can offer.

Comment: Why VBA - it could also be done with formulas only ;-)

Comment: @PeterAlbert ... It doesn't have to be VBA.  I assumed VBA since I initially wracked my brain on how to do this through formulae but it wasn't clicking on how to accomplish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the VBA code to do it - you only need to modify the sheet names and start ranges:

```
Sub MultiplyRows()
    Dim rngSource As Range, rngTarget As Range

    Set rngSource = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")
    Set rngTarget = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2")

    While rngSource <> ""
        rngSource.Resize(, 2).Copy rngTarget.Resize(rngSource.Offset(, 2), 2)
        Set rngTarget = rngTarget.Offset(rngSource.Offset(, 2))
        Set rngSource = rngSource.Offset(1)
    Wend
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you can do this with formulas only:

[image]

The idea is that you use some helper columns to count up and retrieve the data. In detail, I have 3 helper columns with the following logic:

- "Source row", column E: This is the actual row in the source data that this target row refers to. The "column logic" is that it is the same number as in the row above - unless in the row above the counter was equal to the max count. Therefore, the formula in E5 is: `=IF(F4=G4,E4+1,E4)`. You also need to "initialize" the column, i.e. in E4 I used : `=ROW(A3)+1`
- Max count: The number of rows required for the current source row. F4: `=INDEX(C:C;E4)`
- Count: This is the counter, how often the current source row was already filled. The logic is to simply increase the value from above by one - unless the source row in this column is different than last row. G4: `=IF(E4<>E3,1,G3+1)`

Now you only need to use the number stored in column E as the argument for an INDEX function, i.e. copy this formula from H4 down and also to column I: `=INDEX(A:A,E4)`.

Now you only need to copy the formulas for the 5 columns down to the required number of rows. (Remember to copy down column E starting in row 5, but columns F:I in row 4.